How to control Elogation Ratio in scaling on Oval
I have an Oval shaped object (a base for a miniature intending to be 3D printed). It started out life as a circle and I used the X & Y Dimensions to turn it into an Oval.

However I'd like to control the Elongation Ratio. That is to say, I'd like to make it a "fatter" oval with sharper "corners". The red pen on the image shows sorta what I mean.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Hello, there's no magic way to do it, you can try to deform the mesh with the Proportional Editing activated, then symmetrize, if it doesn't work well I guess you need to redo it from scratch
